# Issue while loading into greenplum table using gpload utility

Tags: sql, greenplum

My goal is to load special characters into Greenplum table. I am getting following error.

```
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ gpload -f emp.yaml
2017-03-03 19:55:47|INFO|gpload session started 2017-03-03 19:55:47
2017-03-03 19:55:47|INFO|started gpfdist -p 8000 -P 9000 -f "/home/gpadmin/emp.ftm" -t 30
2017-03-03 19:55:50|ERROR|ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa6  (seg2 slice1 sdw2:40000 pid=16577)
DETAIL:  External table ext_gpload_4b5b4fa4_001d_11e7_88fe_005056a752ea, line 2 of file gpfdist://mdw:8000//home/gpadmin/emp.ftm
encountered while running INSERT INTO "sample"."emp" ("emp_id","emp_name") SELECT "emp_id","emp_name" FROM ext_gpload_4b5b4fa4_001d_11e7_88fe_005056a752ea
2017-03-03 19:55:50|INFO|rows Inserted          = 0
2017-03-03 19:55:50|INFO|rows Updated           = 0
2017-03-03 19:55:50|INFO|data formatting errors = 0
2017-03-03 19:55:50|INFO|gpload failed
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$
```

**emp.yaml** contains:

```
VERSION: 1.0.0.1
DATABASE: tutorial
USER: gpadmin
PASSWORD: Welcome@1
HOST: 172.16.7.104
PORT: 5432
GPLOAD:
 INPUT:
- SOURCE:
   FILE:
     - /home/gpadmin/emp.ftm
- COLUMNS:
- DELIMITER: "\x01"
- FORMAT: CSV
- ESCAPE:
- QUOTE: "\x08"
- ENCODING: "UTF-8"
- ERROR_LIMIT: 0
OUTPUT:
- TABLE: '"sample".emp'
- MODE: INSERT
 PRELOAD:
- TRUNCATE: FALSE
```

**emp.ftm** contains:

```
^H2^H^A^Hpr@deep^H
^H4^H^A^HP¦âdéëp^H
^H1^H^A^Hdeep^H
^H3^H^A^Hprádeep^H
```

Without special characters, I am able to load the above ftm into 'emp' table.
Can someone help on this to load table with special characters.

Comment: Try encoding latin1 to retain the special characters.  If you don't want the special characters, you'l have to remove it with something like perl, sed, tr, etc first.

Comment: After posting this question..I tried with different encodings and found that LATIN1 is working as you mentioned. But I don't understand the difference between LATIN1 and UTF8. UTF-8 supposed to handle this right?

Comment: I believe the problem is your filesystem is not in UTF8 and gpload needs to read the file in a character set that best matches your filesystem.  The data is then stored in UTF8 inside the database so you should be good now.